# QueryBuilder lastInsertId()

Tags: typo3, query-builder, extbase, typo3-9.x

I would like to have the last UID of the entry. For mysql, it is "insertId()". How does that work at Extbase?

```
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable($table);
$queryBuilder
   ->insert($table)
   ->values([
       'test_id'          => 1,
       'test2_id'         => 2,
   ]);

$queryBuilder->execute();

$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable($table2);
$queryBuilder
   ->insert($table2)
   ->values([
       'uid_local'         => ?, // uid from $table
       'uid_foreign'       => 1
   ]);
$queryBuilder->execute();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the last insert id with `$queryBuilder->getConnection()->lastInsertId();`

So that would make it:

```
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable($table);
$queryBuilder
   ->insert($table)
   ->values([
       'test_id'          => 1,
       'test2_id'         => 2,
   ]);

$queryBuilder->execute();
$tableUid = $queryBuilder->getConnection()->lastInsertId();

$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable($table2);
$queryBuilder
   ->insert($table2)
   ->values([
       'uid_local'         => $tableUid,
       'uid_foreign'       => 1
   ]);
$queryBuilder->execute();
```

Comment: No, you need the first $queryBuilder. If you use this code on the place of the question mark you'll use the $queryBuilder for table2. So either rename the first $queryBuilder or put the output of `$queryBuilder->getConnection()->lastInsertId();` in a variable before you replace the $queryBuilder and replace the question mark with that variable. I added an example of the second option (with a variable) to my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unsure if it's available when using the QueryBuilder for inserting new records, but the migration guide in TYPO3 Docs explain how you migrate the sql_insert_id() method in the new Doctrine Database Layer

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Database/Migration/Index.html#sql-insert-id

Hint:

`(int)$databaseConnectionForPages->lastInsertId('pages');`